# Image format issue , when sending mail in android

Tags: android, file, bitmap, uri, email-attachments

I can get the images from the drawable  folder ,using the following code.And also i can send the email also. But the problem is the format of the image is file and i can't open it in my android device.How can i convert this in to any image format like png,jpg etc.

```
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.example.jithu"+ "/" +imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the extension is attached to the image.Try code below:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.example.jithu"+ "/" +imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]) + ".jpg");
intent.setType("image/jpeg");  // attachment is a jpeg
```

Comment: it not working again the output is file format.not image format.thanks for response.